# SQL select multiple rows in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table **TestTable**

```
ID Name
-------
1  A
1  B
1  C 
2  D 
2  E
3  F
```

I want to write a query in SQL Server 2008 which will return

```
ID Name
----------    
1   A,B,C
2   D,E
3   F
```

Please someone help me to write this query.

Comment: have you tried with subqueries?

Comment: old question, but SQL Server 2017 introduced [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 21):

AFAIK, there is no native way to do so. However, you can use the [**`FOR XML`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to do this like so:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Id,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.name  
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Id;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/728c7/7)

This will give you:

```
| ID |   NAMES |
----------------
|  1 | A, B, C |
|  2 |    D, E |
|  3 |       F |
```

Comment: @Gulrej If this solution resolved your problem, consider marking it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this ::

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
        SUBSTRING(d.Name,1, LEN(d.Name) - 1) Name
FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ID
            FROM testTable
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT [Name] + ', ' 
            FROM testTable AS B 
            WHERE A.ID = B.ID 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL server 2008** supports this by using `Pivot or Unpivot` @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It would be better if you show the OP how is the group concatenation can be done using the `PIVOT` table operator.

Comment: Pivot will only create more columns, not put the pivoted data into ONE column, do not go down this path if you want one column.