# Mysql merge rows

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this table:

```
ip   country

1     A
2     A
3     B
4     B
4     B
```

I am trying to write a query, which will return something like:

```
A 1,2
B 3,4
```

E.g. `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY` country returns:

```
A 1
B 3
```

But it's not the desired result.

Ι can run this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ip
```

and **programmatically** will write something like:

```
$c_ip=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
if($row['ip'])!=$c_ip)
{
$c_ip=$row['ip'];
//new line!!
}else
{
//don't close <tr> code goes here
}
}
```

Comment: do you want same country ip comma separated in a row.

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065277/sql-select-multiple-rows-in-one-column)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT country, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip SEPARATOR ',') AS ips 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY country
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f436/13)**

Comment: According to SQL Fiddle it doesn't gives the correct answer. (4 is repeated)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add 'DISTINCT' infront of ip, if you don't want the value 4 to be repeated.

```
SELECT country, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip SEPARATOR ',') AS ids 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Query`, you can use **`STUFF`** in **`SQL SERVER`**

```
   SELECT 
  t1.country,
  STUFF((
    SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(t2.ip as varchar)
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.country = t1.country
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.country;
```

***[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c1d7/6)***

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT country, GROUP_CONCAT(ip)
FROM table1
GROUP BY country
```

[***SQL FIDDLE HERE***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f436/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
              SELECT DISTINCT country, SUBSTRING(ConcateColumn,2,LEN(ConcateColumn))
    FROM Table t1
   CROSS APPLY ( 
                select substring((SELECT  ','  + ip 
                     FROM Table t2
                     WHERE t2.country = t2.country
                     ORDER BY DescOfFault 
                     FOR XML PATH('')),2,20000)
                      )  D ( ConcateColumn )
```